# Java switch directories and then fire command with parameters

Tags: java, process, inputstream, runtime.exec

Hey all I am trying to change directories and then run my command with parameters.

```
final String path = "\\Local// Apps\\IBM\\SDP\\scmtools\\eclipse";
final String command = "scm help";
final String dosCommand = "cmd /c \""  + path + "\"" + command;
final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(dosCommand);
final InputStream in = process.getInputStream();
int ch;

while((ch = in.read()) != -1) {
    System.out.print((char)ch);
}
```

It runs without errors but outputs nothing. However, this is what shows up after it finishes:

```
<terminated, exit value: 0>C:\Local Apps\IBM\SDP\jdk\bin\javaw.exe (Jul 22, 2019, 11:21:37 AM)
```

The expected output should be:

[image]

So am I doing this correctly?

**AS suggested by Andreas**

```
Process p = null;
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("scm.exe");
pb.directory(new File("C:/Local Apps/IBM/SDP/scmtools/eclipse"));
p = pb.start();
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot run program "scm.exe" (in directory "C:\Local Apps\IBM\SDP\scmtools\eclipse"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: No, you should use `ProcessBuilder` instead of `Runtime.exec`, since it supports setting the working directory, sending output straight to the console, etc.

Comment: @Andreas I updated my OP with your suggestion... still does not seem to work.

Comment: What is `scm`? An .exe file? Or a .bat or .cmd file? Something else?

Comment: An .exe file thats in that directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) instead of `Runtime.exec`, e.g.

```
Process proc = new ProcessBuilder("scm.exe", "help")
        .directory(new File("C:\\Local Apps\\IBM\\SDP\\scmtools\\eclipse"))
        .inheritIO()
        .start();
proc.waitFor(); // optional
```

You can also go through the command interpreter if needed, e.g. if the command is a script (.bat or .cmd file):

```
Process proc = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "scm", "help")
        .directory(new File("C:\\Local Apps\\IBM\\SDP\\scmtools\\eclipse"))
        .inheritIO()
        .start();
proc.waitFor();
```

The [`inheritIO()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO--) means that you don't need to process the commands output. It will be sent to the console, or wherever Java's own output would go.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work either: **Cannot run program "scm.exe" (in directory "C:\Local Apps\IBM\SDP\scmtools\eclipse"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified**